# View accurate search results count in Gmail

Tags: gmail, search

Is there way to view the search results returned in Gmail to an exact number?

Let's say I have a friend, who knows this girl, who won't stop emailing him. He's filing for a restraining order, and he wants to put the exact number of times she's emailed him.

When he searches for her email, say using terms `from:psycho.stalker@gmail.com`, the results say "1-20 of Thousands".

Is there a way to determine the exact number, you know, in the interest of filling out the paperwork accurately for the state of California?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create a filter and apply a label. if you then show only mails from that label gmail displays the exact number of mails tagged by this label.