# Why can't Gmail accurately calculate the total count for my search?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Does anyone know the reason that Gmail doesn't accurately show the total results when paging through search results?

In other words, here is a recent set of results I saw while paging:

- 1-50 of many
- 51-100 of 142
- 101-150 of 160
- 151-173 of 173

Why can't it just say "... of 173" the entire time?  (though I'm fine w/ "many" being used when appropriate)

I can't find an article/explanation about it anywhere, but it's been an issue in Gmail for as long as I can remember.

Comment: Related: [View accurate search results count in Gmail](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/4348/354)

Comment: Google does the same thing with all of their search products. I'm certain it's a performance issue. By grabbing the first few results and doing some math, they're returning results more quickly than if they stopped to get the exact count.

Comment: [This article at Search Engine Land](http://searchengineland.com/why-google-cant-count-results-properly-53559) talks about Google's general search, but I expect the same principal applies.